# How Can I Link My Bones With Mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I am 15 years old and I am a beginner in blender and I know how to link armature with mesh.

I downloaded some bones to animate the character, but when I try to link the bones with the character it deforms and I don't know what to do.

If I press with automatic weights that's what happens, it deforms.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I think the order of selection i wrong! the `light orange` object is called active object. your armature should be active object. just select your character first and then select armature and do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the mesh first and then the bones. The bones need to be the brighter orange.
If you have a character with different sections you may also need to select "With Envelope Weights".
I hope this helps. It is hard to answer such a question without the actual file.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HCiAa4k

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AObcFBma_c_y-0ngVePdOO0Nijzm6ecF/view